# What are the consequenses for my domain of non malicious email spoofing?

Tags: email, spam

I have an application:
User fills out webform on my server
Server emails the form to another server as an email
We want the FROM to be the user's email, but it's coming from our server, to another of our servers.

Question, we're sending emails across the internet that are spoofed. No one else can see this, but will intermediate hops get upset and black list us?

Comment: Is the destination address one that you control? If so, why would there be intermediate hops?

Comment: IDK, that's my question. If I send an email from serverA.com -> serverB.com, doesn't that get bounced around a bunch of intermediate servers? I thought that there is some level of spam filtering that happens between the nodes on the internet. Is this in anyway dangerous to my domain if I am spoofing the emails in a non-malicious way?

Comment: The application is that the users are filling out a form, and then the form gets emailed from my server, but I want it to appear that they sent it themselves. Is this a concern for my domain?

Comment: Why not just put their email in the text of the message. Wouldn't you want to later be able to differentiate between actual emails from them and the original form? Until you verify the email address it may not even be a real one and it could be confusing to have a record of receiving one from them.

Comment: LOL no sh*t! I totally agree stvcisco! I was actually trying to arm myself with reasons NOT to do this. I don't really want to do it like this, I'm being forced to by a touchy client who isn't a programmer.